# Save variable value in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to SAVE the value of a variable (say an integer) in python? 
My problem involves calling (entering and exiting) multiple times the same python script (python file, not python function) which in the end creates a txt file. I'd like to name the txt files depending on the number of times the python code was called: txt1.txt,..., txt100.txt for example.

EDIT:
The question is not related with the SAVE parameter in fortran. My mistake.

Comment: what have you tried so far? give it a go, maybe try looking on google 'compose python strings' (to create your filename) and then 'create file with python' and it should come up fairly easy to understand :)

Comment: The `pickle` and `shelf` modules both provide some interface for storing some constant values in files that persist between executions of a program.  I'd look into those to start.

Comment: You might want to tell users that Fortran's `save` works like C's `static` to clarify what you mean.  There are more C users here than Fortran ones.

Comment: post edit: so are you wondering how to write a text file, or do you want to know how to preserve a variable's value across calls to a function?

Comment: Your clarification here is good ... But you still need to explain better what you mean by "entering and exiting the same python code".  that could easily be interpreted as entering and exiting the same function within a script or calling the script multiple times.

Comment: @MrFooz: I'll run a program which will call multiple times a certain python script. At the end of each call (note that by call I mean entering the python script, performing the operations and exit the python script) a txt file will be created. I want to differentiate the multiple txt files by their name which should depend on the number of the times the python script was called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE:** I'm assuming that what you mean by:

> calling (entering and exiting) multiple times the same python code

is that you want to call the whole Python script multiple times, in which case you need to serialize your counter in some way external to the Python interpreter, to make it available next time. If you're just asking about calling the same function or method several times within one Python session, you can do that a variety of ways and I'd point you to [mgilson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16342602/2069350).

There are plenty of ways to serialize things, but your implementation doesn't really have anything to do with the language. Do you want to store it in a database? Write the value to a file? Or is it enough to just retrieve an appropriate value from context? For instance, this code will get you a new file each time it is called, based on the contents of `output_dir`. It's obviously rough, but you get the idea:

```
import os

def get_next_filename(output_dir):
    '''Gets the next numeric filename in a sequence.

    All files in the output directory must have the same name format,
    e.g. "txt1.txt".
    '''

    n = 0
    for f in os.listdir(output_dir):
        n = max(n, int(get_num_part(os.path.splitext(f)[0])))
    return 'txt%s.txt' % (n + 1)

def get_num_part(s):
    '''Get the numeric part of a string of the form "abc123".

    Quick and dirty implementation without using regex.'''

    for i in xrange(len(s)):
        if s[i:].isdigit():
            return s[i:]
    return ''
```

Or of course you can just write a file called something like `runnum.cfg` somewhere next to the Python script, and write your current run number into it, then read that when the code launches.

Comment: I like the directory scanning to get the next number approach.  +1.

Comment: This "let the files themselves be the system state" pattern is one I often use myself.

Comment: @HenryKeiter: I believe you assume a file already exists in the folder. Am I right?

Comment: @jpcgandre I was when I first wrote it, but I've since edited the answer so it'll work whether or not any files already exist in the folder. (Just change `n` to begin at 0 instead of 1).

Answer (score 7):

Not really.  The best you can do is to use a global variable:

```
counter = 0
def count():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print counter
```

An alternative which bypasses the need for the global statement would be something like:

```
from itertools import count
counter = count()
def my_function():
    print next(counter)
```

or even:

```
from itertools import count
def my_function(_counter=count()):
    print next(_counter)
```

A final version takes advantage of the fact that functions are first class objects and can have attributes added to them whenever you want:

```
def my_function():
    my_function.counter += 1
    print my_function.counter

my_function.counter = 0 #initialize.  I suppose you could think of this as your `data counter /0/ statement.
```

---

However, it looks like you actually want to save the count within a file or something.  That's not too hard either.  You just need to pick a filename:

```
def count():
    try:
        with open('count_data') as fin:
            i = int(count_data.read())
    except IOError:
        i = 0
    i += 1
    print i
    with open('count_data','w') as fout:
        fout.write(str(i))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @HenryKeiter -- Do you know fortran?  (I do -- pretty well).  I believe that it answers the question just fine.  when you exit a function, in python, everything is gone.  There is no `save`.

Comment: @HenryKeiter: what exactly do you think the question *is*?

Comment: For those who are wondering, the `save` statement in fortran is somewhat akin to `static` in `C`.  The value of a variable is preserved between calls of the function.

Comment: The question is really related to what @mgilson wrote: I need to define a counter to count the number of times the code was called and then create a txt file with the name `'name' + counter`. I just need to know how can I define a variable that does not lose its value between calls.

Comment: @DSM I'm assuming he wants to preserve a variable between calls of his Python script: "I'd like to name the txt files depending on the number of times the python code was called". So he needs to serialize it somehow, not preserve it within the Python.

Comment: I heard that pickling can do this sort of stuff...but is its use recommended?

Comment: @HenryKeiter -- That's not what `save` does in fortran.  `save` does nothing between invocations of the program.

Comment: @HenryKeiter: You are right. Between calls I mean between calls to the python script. Thanks

Comment: @jpcgandre -- Wait.  You mean `python myscript` gives `file1` then `python myscript` gives `file2` and so on?  Because you won't get that with fortran's `save`.  you need to clarify what you're asking here ...

Comment: @jpcgandre: wait, what?  So by like the fortran save you mean "nothing at all like the fortran save"?  Fortran's save doesn't serialize.

Comment: @DSM -- ha ha -- Thanks for sticking with me on this one.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @mgilson: I use save in fortran to store variables. I don't know if it saves the variables between runs of the fortran code or just consecutive calls of the functions. I used a program that compiled the fortran code along with the execution of an external program that called the fortran code in loops.... and I need to add the save parameter for not losing information.

Comment: Ignoring the multiple script execution issue, I suppose the strict equivalent of Fortran's `save` would be something like `globals()["counter"]=theValue`, right? But that would be a fairly horrific approach to take. This answer is better from a structured programming point of view.

Comment: @Kylotan -- Yes, I suppose so with the caveat that Fortran has no global namespace, so the `counter` is only accessible to the function where it is defined (and `save`d).

Comment: Removed my downvote since the question is still so ambiguous. :)

Answer (score 1):

[mgilson's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16342602/25050) provides good options to the original question.  Another approach is to refactor the code to separate the concerns of choosing filenames from computing + saving.  Here's a code sketch:

```
for i in ...:
   filename = 'txt%d.txt' % (i,)
   do_something_then_save_results(..., filename)
```

If you need to do this in a lot of places and want to reduce code duplication, a generator function can be useful:

```
def generate_filenames(pattern, num):
   for i in xrange(num):
       yield pattern % (i,)

...
for filename in generate_filenames('txt%d.txt', ...):
   do_something_then_save_results(..., filename)
```

Replace "..." with whatever's meaningful in your application.